# How to get Liferay site name from inside Portlet class?

Tags: java, portlet, liferay-6.2

I can get the current Liferay site name from JSP:

```
<%= themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroup().getName() %>
```

It gives for instance "Guest".

**QUESTION**: How to get the same **from the Java Portlet class**?

The closest I have found are the `PortalUtil.getLayoutURL` methods but I don't want an URL as the site name from the URL is all lowercase and potentially different from the real site name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or simply:

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) renderRequest
            .getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) renderRequest
            .getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);    
GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId()).getName();
```